# How to create a menu item with UAC-shield in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a menu item for an action that will require elevation.

The Windows UI guidelines state that such actions should have the UAC-shield displayed next to them.

How can I do that using plain Windows API and C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Windows shell does provide various default icons, among which is also the UAC-shield icon.

Loading the icon

```
SHSTOCKICONINFO ssii = {};
ssii.cbSize = sizeof(ssii);
SHGetStockIconInfo(SIID_SHIELD, SHGSI_ICON | SHGSI_SMALLICON, &ssii);
```

This gives you a `HICON`, however `SetMenuItemBitmaps` requires a `HBITMAP` so the `HICON` needs to be converted:

```
ICONINFOEX iconInfo = {};
iconInfo.cbSize = sizeof(iconInfo);
GetIconInfoEx(ssii.hIcon, &iconInfo);
auto bitmap = (HBITMAP)CopyImage(iconInfo.hbmColor, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

Finally, set the icon:

```
SetMenuItemBitmaps(hMenu, YOUR_MENU_ITEM_COMMAND, MF_BYCOMMAND, bitmap, bitmap);
```

Clean-up:

```
DestroyIcon(ssii.hIcon);
```

`bitmap` needs to be destroyed after the menu is destroyed (using `DeleteObject(bitmap);`), or will be cleaned up when the application shuts down, as described in [CopyImage(MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-copyimage) and [SetMenuItemBitmaps(MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setmenuitembitmaps).

Comment: Don't forget to delete the bitmaps.

Comment: and `DestroyIcon(ssii.hIcon);` too